# Remove trend line from a Power BI line chart with continuous x-axis

Tags: charts, user-interface, microsoft-powerbi, data-visualization, trendlines

I need to remove the trend line from my Power BI line chart. The trend line was automatically generated and is not meaningful in my data analysis. I can't find an option to remove it. The trend line disappears if the x-axis type is changed to "categorical," but that's not an acceptable solution because I need the x-axis type to remain "continuous." The trend line in the image below is the dotted black line. Thank you for any help.

[image: Line chart with unwanted trend line]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trend line can be turned off by first clicking on the magnifying glass icon in the Visualizations pane to open the Analytics tab, then click the "Trend line" slider to "Off."

[image: Top of Visualizations Analytics pane showing Trend line option]